# access violation Exception thrown: write access violation. window.vertexBuffer was 0x1110112

Tags: c++

I'm getting an access violation.

I have tried pointing the *vertexBuffer* to an initialized int array but i got the same result.

I have done some debugging to see whats going one but it seems that my variables are not initialized properly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class CmdGame
{
private:
    int bufferSizeX, bufferSizeY;
    char *buffer;
    bool good = false;
    int vertexLeng = 0;
    int *vertexBuffer;

public:
    static CmdGame intialize(int width, int height);

    static void clearBuffer(CmdGame window);

    static void vetex2I(int x, int y, CmdGame window);

    static void drawArrays(int type, CmdGame window);

    static void shangeBuffer(CmdGame window);
};

CmdGame CmdGame::intialize(int width, int height)
{
    CmdGame Buffer;
    Buffer.bufferSizeX = width;
    Buffer.bufferSizeY = height;
    CmdGame::clearBuffer(Buffer);
    Buffer.good = true;

    return Buffer;
}

void CmdGame::shangeBuffer(CmdGame window)
{
    printf(window.buffer);
}

void CmdGame::vetex2I(int x, int y, CmdGame window)
{

    window.vertexBuffer[window.vertexLeng] = y;
    window.vertexBuffer[window.vertexLeng + 1] = x;

    window.vertexLeng++;
}

void CmdGame::clearBuffer(CmdGame window)
{
    system("CLS");
    delete window.buffer;
    window.buffer = new char[window.bufferSizeX * window.bufferSizeY];
    delete window.vertexBuffer;
    window.vertexBuffer = new int[99 * 2];
}

void CmdGame::drawArrays(int type, CmdGame window)
{
    if (type == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i += 3)
        {

        }
    }
    if(type == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i += 2)
        {
            window.buffer[window.vertexBuffer[i] * window.vertexBuffer[i + 1]] = '#';
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    CmdGame window = CmdGame::intialize(64, 32);

    while (true)
    {
        CmdGame::clearBuffer(window);

        CmdGame::vetex2I(32, 16, window);

        CmdGame::drawArrays(0,window);

        CmdGame::shangeBuffer(window);
    }
}
```

expecting to set the the value of `vertexBuffer[i]` but it gives this:

> Exception thrown: write access violation.
>   window.vertexBuffer was 0x1110112.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to initialize your two buffers in the `initialize()` function! Doesn't matter, so long as you use the `.good` flag in 'clearBuffer':

```
void CmdGame::clearBuffer(CmdGame window)
{
    if (window.good) { // Has buffers already …
        delete[] window.buffer; // You need delete[] 'cos you used new []!
        delete[] window.vertexBuffer;
    }
    system("CLS");
    window.buffer = new char[window.bufferSizeX * window.bufferSizeY];
    window.vertexBuffer = new int[99 * 2];
}
```

Then try again!